# Flush the extracted file to the disk in python

Tags: python

This is my code :

```
 x=zipfile.ZipFile('C://X/malware.zip')
    for i in range(1):        
        x.extractall('C://E',pwd='infected')
        start=time.clock()
        print str(start)
        while flag==1:
            if os.path.exists('C://E/malware.exe')==True:
                flag=1
            else:
                flag=0

    finish=time.clock()
    print str(finish)
    elapsed=finish-start
    print "the time elapsed is " + str(elapsed)+"seconds"
```

I need the extraction written directly to the disk ,,,how I can make flush to the file that is being extracted ,,,???

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be laboring under the belief that you need to wait for the zip file to be extracted. That's not how Python works. When your `x.extractall()` finishes, it's done. The file has been extracted and closed, so it has already been flushed to disk.

Also, even if you did need to wait, this:

```
 while flag==1:
    if os.path.exists('C://E/malware.exe')==True:
       flag=1
    else:
       flag=0
```

is so wrong in so many ways that I don't even know where to begin. But it would be better written as:

```
while not os.path.exists('C://E/malware.exe'):
    time.sleep(0.01)   # don't use all the CPU by checking constantly!
```

Comment: My Code must calculate the time from the extraction of the virus  to the time that it is scanned and deleted by the antivirus ,,,Please ,if you have an idea more accurate than this tell me ,